# Check change property object

Tags: python

I have two classes, for example

```
class First(Some_Base1):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 1

class Second(Some_Base2):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.stat = First()
```

How can i check, that the x has changed, inside Second?

```
s = Second()
s.stat.x = 0
```

If i use `__setattr__` inside Second, it wont work, but would in First.
If use `@stat.setter` - same reason.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "check".

Comment: I can't understand the question. Determining whether a value has changed, is a separate task from changing it. You say that you want to "check that the x has changed", but then you show or discuss several attempts to change a value.

Comment: @chepner find out, that property of First has changed, in Second.
@KarlKnechtel maybe i was unclear. When i write about `__setattr__`, i try to know, that like
<code>
class Second(Some_Base2):
   ...
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if name == 'stat':
</code>

Comment: Changed since *when*? The last time you looked at `s.stat.x`, or as soon as possible after `s.stat.x` has been assigned to? There's a difference between "check" and "be notified".

Comment: Just before change or right after

Answer (score 0):

You cat add @stat.getter in to Second class and after every geting stat, check if stat.x was changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can record a change in the `First` itself using `__setattr__`.

For eg.

```
class First(Some_Base1):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 1
        self.__x_changed = False
    
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super(First, self).__setattr__(key, value)
        if key == "x":
            self.__x_changed = True

    @property
    def has_x_changed(self):
        return self.__x_changed
```

And in `Second` you can check the change like

```
s1 = Second()
s1.stat.x = 0
# It will return True
s.stat.has_x_changed

s2 = Second()
# It will return False
s2.stat.has_x_changed
```